# Is it possible to paint a QGraphicsItem inside the paint() method?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, pyside

I'm creating a subclass of QGraphicsItem, and this subclass has different places that the user can click.
My idea is for each component clicked to create a subclass of QGraphicsItem with mousePressEvent replaced. The problem is how can I merge this component into a subclass of QGraphicItem.

Here's the code I'm trying, but I do not know how to show all the components in the paint method.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class GraphicItemMain(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(GraphicItemMain, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        textComponent = GraphicItemTextClicked(5+self.x, 5+self.y)
        ellipseComponent = GraphicItemEllipseClicked(5+self.x, 50+self.y)
        # How do I print this components?

class GraphicItemTextClicked(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(GraphicItemTextClicked, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #Do something
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.x, self.y, 80, 30)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0), 1))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(QtCore.QPointF(3+self.x, self.y), "Same Text")

class GraphicItemEllipseClicked(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(GraphicItemEllipseClicked, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #Do other thing
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.x, self.y, 25, 25)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0), 1))
        painter.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 25, 25)
```

Comment: Can you explain me better?

Comment: You don't need to do anything in the parent QGraphicsItem paint method to display the children. That is handled in their own paint methods. Add the child items in the parent's __init__method, not the paint method. Otherwise new children will be added again every time paint() is called.

Comment: Thanks @SimonHibbs , the solution was to call textComponent.setParentItem(self) and ellipseComponent.setParentItem(self) on __init__ method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @SimonHibbs , the solution was to call textComponent.setParentItem(self) and ellipseComponent.setParentItem(self) on **init** method.

Solution:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class GraphicItemMain(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(GraphicItemMain, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        textComponent = GraphicItemTextClicked(5+self.x, 5+self.y)
        textComponent.setParentItem(self)
        ellipseComponent = GraphicItemEllipseClicked(5+self.x, 50+self.y)
        ellipseComponent.setParentItem(self)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # Paint samething

class GraphicItemTextClicked(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(GraphicItemTextClicked, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Do something
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.x, self.y, 80, 30)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0), 1))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(QtCore.QPointF(3+self.x, self.y), "Same Text")

class GraphicItemEllipseClicked(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(GraphicItemEllipseClicked, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, False)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Do other thing
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.x, self.y, 25, 25)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0), 1))
        painter.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 25, 25)
```